# How can I run a PHP CLI program in the console in Eclipse PDT?

Tags: php, eclipse

I can only open PHP Command-line Interface programs in browsers in Eclipse PDT. I want to run it in the command line so that I can get the user's keyboard input.

Comment: This question is about programming and would belong on [so]

Comment: Duplicate with SO - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11726450/missing-run-as-php-script-in-eclipse - answer is there

Comment: Technically, this question is about a program, not about programming, however it seems that the program dictates that programming programs are programmed to be on SO’s program instead of here.